# Attribute error when creating a vbox in gtk3 python3

Tags: python-3.x, attributes, gtk3

I have a Dialog box in gtk3 and am trying to create a vbox and hbox, both of which fail miserably with can't set attribute error.  I have looked at the documentation and am trying variations of spacing=x and calling directly the new method.

```
class MacroDialog(Gtk.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, id_):
        Gtk.Dialog.__init__(self, 'Record Macros', parent)
        self.set_default_size(150, 100)
        self.set_has_resize_grip(False)

        #create widgets, layout
        self.box = self.get_content_area()
        self.vbox = Gtk.Box.new(Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, 10)
        self.hbox = Gtk.Box.new(Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, 6)
```

I cannot figure out why this attribute error is happening, could someone provide some insight

Answer (score 0):

Ended up solving this problem by renaming self.vbox, self.hbox => self.v_box and self.h_box
Also reused the box, self.get_content_area() as my v_box by setting the orientation, the folowing works:

```
class MacroDialog(Gtk.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, id_):
        Gtk.Dialog.__init__(self, 'Record Macros', parent)
        self.set_default_size(150, 100)
        self.set_has_resize_grip(False)

        #create widgets, layout
        self.v_box = self.get_content_area()
        self.v_box.set_orientation(Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        #self.v_box = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=10)
        self.h_box = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, spacing=10)
        self.scrollWindow = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        self.scrollWindow.set_policy(Gtk.PolicyType.AUTOMATIC, Gtk.PolicyType.AUTOMATIC)
        self.macroEdit = Gtk.TextView()
        self.macroEdit.set_editable(False)
        self.scrollWindow.add(self.macroEdit)

        self.clearBtn = Gtk.Button('Clear')
        self.saveBtn = Gtk.Button('Save')

        #add widgets
        self.v_box.pack_start(self.scrollWindow, True, True, 0)
        self.h_box.pack_start(self.clearBtn, True, True, 0)
        self.h_box.pack_start(self.saveBtn, True, True, 0)
        self.v_box.pack_start(self.h_box, True, True, 0)
        self.v_box.add(self.h_box)
```